# MYSQL Fulltext index search, cant get my head round it

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, freetext

Hi guys i've written/borrowed some code to allow free text searching on my site what i'm ending up with is the following search string for a simple search, I only started learning PHP,MYDSQL, Jquery a couple of weeks ago so its probably easy:

```
SELECT * match (body) against (' cleaning office ') as relevance
FROM jobs
WHERE match (jobbody) against ('cleaning')>0
    AND match (body) against ('office')>0
HAVING relevance>0
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

This throws a syntax error, I know its a really simple question but I just cant seem to get my head round where i'm going wrong, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to do and give us a basic idea of your table structure?

Comment: Yeah sorry I have a textbox on my site that creates an SQL search string from the typed input, if I type cleaner AND office it generates that search string which then flies off and generates a grid, trouble is if I use that query it doesnt even work in phpmyadmin. I probably have the syntax wrong in the query itself

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to find in your SQL tables based on the user input? What are your tables? I have never had to do more than just a simple SELECT * FROM tableNAME WHERE MATCH(tableName.col) AGAINST ('userInput');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a comma after the `SELECT *`. That appears to be where your syntax error is coming from.

Also, for next time, be sure to post the syntax error you're getting. MySQL errors are usually pretty helpful and informative.

Comment: Excellent thanks Francis, cant believe I missed that i've been staring at it for about an hour,

Comment: @thatidiotguy sorry I wasnt trying to be difficult I know my table structure and FULLTEXT index are correct so I was 100% positive it was a syntax error in the query itself.

Comment: Glad that worked for you! That happens a lot when staring at code too long :) Please mark the question as answered!